# Stop image loading while scroll fast in ListView/Recyclerview android?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I wanted to Stop image loading while scroll fast in ListView/Recyclerview android.

Comment: Why do you want to stop it??

Comment: What image library do you use?

Comment: if i m scrolling fast the images download gets que and i want to stop them and downoad only visible images to user whent they stop the list

Comment: But what im asking you is why do you want to do that?? Specify the issue you have currently on loading all the images

Comment: I want to increase the performace and bandwidth of recycle view and i have 1000 items in list and i scroll to last then wats the need of downloading 1000 images

Comment: If you want to increase performence then thats not the solution.. Which is the image library you are using ??

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance of listview/recyclerview use below tricks :
1. memory catching,so that images will load faster.For this directly some libraries are available like:
1.Glide
2.Picasso
3.Universal image loader etc.

2.Avoid/minimize conditions in getview/onbindViewHolder.
3.Avoid too much logic writing in getview/onbindViewHolder.

Using such a tricks performance can be increase.